# How to access users mailbox using admin access token

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk, gmail-api, google-directory-api

I got access token for admin user. Now I have to use gmail api to retrieve users gmail metadata of my domain as usual like REST api.

Ex: https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/threads?access_token=user_access_token

Now I have to get same user threads by using admin token

https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/user_id/threads?access_token=admin_access_token>

Am i doing this in correct way or suggest me the best way to sort out this issue.

Comment: I would recommend to refer this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads)

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest leveraging an [OAuth2 Service Account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount) (Signed JWT).  When properly configured, you can specify a 'sub' parameter as any user within your domain.

Comment: How can i set admin consent for my app for accessing all users mail metadata.